# How do the reference and modified bits of the page table entry affect paging? 

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging

I am reading up on paging and memory management unit on wikipedia. How does reference and modified bit of the page table entry affects the operation of paging?

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit
http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring the *accessed* and *dirty* bits. These bits solely exist to aid the implementation of a memory manager and do not affect the working of the MMU.

From Intel's manual, [Volume 3: System Programming](http://communities.intel.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/5061-102-1-8118/Pentium_SW_Developers_Manual_Vol3_SystemProgramming.pdf), Section 3.6.4 (I've compacted two points into one since they are nearly identical, *italic* text holds only for the dirty bit):

> Accessed (A) flag, bit 5 - *Dirty (D) flag, bit 6*
>
> Indicates whether a page (or page table) has
> been accessed (*written to*) when set.
> *(This flag is not used in page-directory entries that point to page tables.)*
> Memory management
> software typically clears this flag when a page or page table is
> initially loaded into physical memory. The processor then sets this
> flag the first time a page (or page table) is accessed (*for a write operation*). This flag is a
> “sticky” flag, meaning that once set, the processor does not
> implicitly clear it. Only software can clear this flag. **The accessed
> and dirty flags are provided for use by memory management software to
> manage the transfer of pages and page tables into and out of physical
> memory.**

Comment: Nice answer for a pretty old question.  We could use more of these kinds of answers for old, unloved questions.

Comment: @Job I am not able to understand `Indicates whether a page (or page table) has been accessed (written to) when set`. How a page can be set without being accessed?